# Why does the Java extends baseclass need the main(string[]) method

Tags: java, extends

this is the code of baseclass:

```
class Base
{
    public double size;
    public String name;
    public Base(double size,String name)
    {
        this.size=size;
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

this is the code of subclass:

```
 public class Sub extends Base
{
    public String color;
    public Sub(double size,String name,String color)
    {
        super(size,name);
        this.color=color;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        var s=new Sub(5.6,"Te`enter code here`st","Green");
        System.out.println(s.size+"---"+s.name+"---"+s.color);
    }
}
```

Start compiling:  javac Sub.java ;is good.
Start running: java Sub.java ; in class not find main(String[]) method
what's going on?

Comment: Did you mean to say that you run it with `java Sub.class`?

Comment: no, my cmd order is :  java Sub.java

Comment: Ok.  That's wrong, then.  You name source files to the Java compiler, but *classes* to the VM launcher.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928.  You >should< run just `java Sub`.

Comment: Run `java Sub`.